# IIS ARR reverse proxy for single website hosted on IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy

I have many sites hosted on IIS on same machine. Only for one site, I need to have reverse proxy setup. I have written rewrite rules for this site and forward some request to another site hosted on different machine.

Will enabling proxy on application request routing affect other sites? Will it have an affect the performance of other sites?

Eg: I have following websites(few are wcf services)

```
localhost/A
localhost/B
localhost/C
localhost/D
```

Only the website C needs reverse proxy, so I have written rewrite rules for it.   How will enabling proxy effect A, B and D sites

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can enable Reverse proxy for one website and ensure that it does not affect the others.

You mentioned that you have 4 websites but in the example, you gave description of "application" and not website. Since its unclear what your architecture looks like, I'll go ahead and give solution to both.

Considering you have a single website and multiple applications within it but you want to enable proxy for just one application, following is what you need to do. Open the URL rewrite section, under pattern, choose regular expression and add ^application_name/(.*) For example, ^c/(.)

But if you have multiple websites and want to reverse proxy just one of them, then open URL Rewrite and add a condition for "HTTP_HOST" and its value. This will ensure that only requests for specific website's hostname will be reverse proxied.

With respect to performance, having URL rewrite on one of the websites will not have any impact on other websites. If you are still unsure and want to play it safe, you can have each website running on separate application pool. That way they have their own w3wp process and are independent of each other.

Comment: to clarify, I have mutiple applications (A, B, C and D where A, B could be WCF services and D another website) hosted on same IIS. I have rewritten rewrite rule for C by modifying it's web.config.

Comment: I have another question.. Can an out bound rule be triggered without a matching inbound rule?

Comment: Yes ! Inbound and Outbound rules are independent of each other.